# iOS 10 Back button width in NavigationBar

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, width, backbarbuttonitem

**Problem:** backBarButtonItem has *extra space* in iOS 10.

**iOS 11**
[image: iOS 11]
**iOS 10**
[image: iOs 10]

As you can see from images above. Back button in iOS 10 has an extra space.

According to [this source](http://www.matrixprojects.net/p/uibarbuttonitem-ios11/)

[image: this source]

**My implementation**

In AppDelegate

```
    UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = ColorHelper.bckgTextTitleWhite
    UINavigationBar.appearance().backIndicatorImage = UIImage(named: "back-button")
    UINavigationBar.appearance().backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = UIImage(named: "back-button")
```

In ViewController

```
    let backBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(back(_:)))
    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backBarButton
```

**I want to achieve the same UI in iOS 10 as in iOS 11.**

Comment: Is this your actual code? How do you add the additional "list" item?

Comment: I add 3 BarButtonItem in story board (1 to left list, 2 to right list) and set „leftItemsSupplementBackButton“ checkbox.

Comment: You could try setting the `leftBarButtonItems` instead, with your back button (requiring a custom icon) and the additional buttons. I usually set navbar buttons this way and never encountered the layout issue you have.

Comment: I have already thought about it and it works! But I am looking for more elegant way.

Comment: Please define "elegant" in this context :)